# how to sort a json data according to date in angular?

Tags: json, angular

I have fetched json data from api. Now I want to sort the response according to descending order of date. I am new to Angular so Please help with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add some of your cade of html and ts?

Comment: @KumariSaloni Please check my answer Update Part . Best wished. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution given below=>

**NEW UPDATE**

if your data is like below

```
 mydata= { "data": [ { "queryid" : "1", "date" : "21/09/2021", "ref_no" : "2345" } ] };
```

Then

Try This

```
get sortMyData() {
    return this.mydata['data'].sort((a, b) => {
      return <any>new Date(b.date) - <any>new Date(a.date);
    });
  }
```

Check the link =>I have updated my code [Link Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-sort-array-of-object-by-date-zcu7vo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdynamicform%2Fdynamicform.component.ts).

**OLD Solution**

**JSON DATA:**

```
data = [
    {
      CREATEDate: "2018-08-15 17:17:30.0",
      Key1: "Val1",
      Key2: "Val2",
    },
    {
      CREATEDate: "2018-08-15 17:25:30.0",
      Key1: "Val1",
      Key2: "Val2",
    },
    {
      CREATEDate: "2018-08-15 17:28:30.0",
      Key1: "Val1",
      Key2: "Val2",
    }
  ]
```

**Sorting Function:**

```
get sortData() {
    return this.data.sort((a, b) => {
      return <any>new Date(b.CREATEDate) - <any>new Date(a.CREATEDate);
    });}
```

**Display DATA=>HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of sortData">
  {{item.Key1}} -- {{item.CREATEDate}} 
</div>
```

**NOTE:** CHECK [Link StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-sort-array-of-object-by-date-9rlpoh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdynamicform%2Fdynamicform.component.html)

Comment: Hi, my json file is like this:       
 { 
"data": [
{
"queryid" : "1",
"date" : "21/09/2021",
"ref_no" : "2345"
}
]
}

Comment: @SJNF, a date in the way dd/MM/YYYY is not a well-known format, so you can not use Date("21/09/2021")

Answer (score 0):

@Kumari, when we work with dates we need take account is we are working with "string" or with real Date. In your case you has a "string" (furthermore, in format dd/MM/YYYY) so you need transform your data adding a new property, or a Date or a String.

See that if the date is a string in format "YYYY/MM/dd" you can sort normally because always  "2021/01/29" is less than "2021/02/12" (the 29th of January is less that the 12th of Febrary) -but "29/01/2021" is bigger than "12/02/2021"-

So, you can, e.g.

```
datasort=this.data.map(x=>({
      ...x, //all the properties of x plus
            //a new propertie of date "normalized"
      dataFormated:x.date.substr(6)+x.date.substr(3,2)+x.date.substr(0,2)})
      ).sort((a:any,b:any)=>a.dataFormated>b.dataFormated?1:
                     a.dataFormated<b.dataFormated?-1:0)
```

or

```
  datasort=this.mydata.data.map(x=>({
      ...x, //all the properties of x plus
            //a new propertie of date "normalized"
      dataFormated:new Date(x.date.substr(6)+"-"+
                   x.date.substr(3,2)+"-"+
                   x.date.substr(0,2))})
      )
      .sort((a:any,b:any)=>a.dataFormated.getTime()-b.dataFormated.getTime())
```